# How can I speed up PowerShell cmdlets that are using the -CimSession parameter?

Tags: performance, powershell, session

As the title says, how could someone speed up the execution of this tiny script? Am I using the New-CimSession that right way anyway?

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=W2012,OU=Servers,DC=contoso,DC=com" -Filter *

foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
    Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "SomeTask" -CimSession (New-CimSession -ComputerName $computer.Name) 
}
```

Comment: Would using `-SkipTestConnection` improve speed by a lot?

Answer (score 1):

Look into using background jobs for the Get-ScheduledTask cmdlet. This will run the command asynchronously.

```
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    start-job -scriptblock {
        #Parse Args
        $CompName = $args[0]
        $TaskName = $args[1]

        Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -CimSession (New-CimSession -ComputerName $CompName)
    } -name( "SchedTask_$($computer)" ) -ArgumentList $computer, "Task Name"
}
```

After which you need to wait until your jobs are in a "Completed" state and then use Receive-Job to get the output. [Geek School: Learn How to Use Jobs in PowerShell](http://www.howtogeek.com/138856/geek-school-learn-how-to-use-jobs-in-powershell/)

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=W2012,OU=Servers,DC=contoso,DC=com" -Filter *
$sessions = New-CimSession -ComputerName $computers.Name

Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "SomeTask" -CimSession $sessions
```

Comment: It's often helpful to explain your answer so people know what it's doing and why it's the right way to do it.